# COUNT for table and Paginator in CakePHP

Tags: php, count, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have a model `Catalog` that is like this:

```
class Catalog extends AppModel {
  public $hasMany = array(
    'Entries' => array(
      'className' => 'Entry',
    );
  );
}
```

In my `index` view, I want to show the number of `Entries` per `Catalog`. I also want to make it possible for the user to sort the `Catalogs` by the number of `Entries`.

I'm a beginner with CakePHP, is there any way I can get the `COUNT(entry_id)` per `Catalog` and display it in the array? And to have it sorted via `$this->Paginator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) with custom query

### in your Model

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'entry_count' => 'SELECT COUNT(entry_id) FROM entries as Entry WHERE Entry.catalog_id = Catalog.id'
  );
```